# rollback PHP - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, transactions, rollback

I am new to CI and PHP too.

I have a form that which add a company and its contacts to the server including file upload .

i need all things on one button click.

so

```
function create_company()
{

 $insert = $this->database->insert();

 return $insert["insertID"]; //returns the inserted ID

}

function file_upload()
{

//upload files if there are some file input selected

return $array_of_uploaded_files;
}

function insert_contacts($company_id,$contacts_array)
{
//return true if everything success

}
```

My problems are

1. **First Company insertion is success,but failed to add its contacts,then i need to delete the current inserted item**
2. **If insert_contact failed i need to delete the uploaded files**

So is there any way to roll back actions if one or more of its dependency failed ?

I know transactions in Codeignitor ,but how can i use it [with multiple function scope] ?

What about file upload ?

Please note that i am asking this question because i am new to php , what i can do is that create so many functions and call it on appropriate situations.

I just want to know that how can i improve or simplify my codes...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use transactions?

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html

So something like:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
// your database queries
$this->db->trans_end();
```

Check if there's any error with the transaction by:

```
$this->db->trans_status();
```

Comment: Thanks ... i want transaction happened in one function and checking in another function is this possible ?currenty i have records for successful/failed operations ... and what about file uploads ? any clue ... :)

Comment: Sure, $this->db is singular and can be used across all your models and controllers. So start your db->transaction() in your controller and if you encounter an error in your models, just don't call trans_end().